# Good beginner camera for sports

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I am looking for a camera for around $1000 to take action shots of horses.  The horses would be moving around 20 miles per hour.

Comment: Outdoors in daylight? Or indoors in a typically poorly lit arena?

Comment: And how close are you going to be to the horses?

Comment: For that budget you will have to rent your lenses. Otherwise do you have a budget for lenses?

Comment: Is that a new camera body, a body alone or something to rent?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's got more to do with the setting than the camera. Any good SLR for $1000 should do the trick.

Comment: Which settings? Can it be done for less than $1000?

Comment: "Good" is still subjective.

Answer (score 0):

I think a general answer would be:
- any camera that can focus fast (so point-n-shoot is not likely an option)
- a lens to go with the dSLR that can focus fast (some cheaper lenses may still give you some "lag")
- a lens with enough "reach" (focal length) so you can visually see the target subject without it being too small; so you may want image stabilizer if you are at long focal lengths
- a camera with a frame rate that is fast enough to capture multiple frames per second

So for example (since I am a Canon shooter, I can only recommend what I know), a good starting camera setup would be:
a Canon 50D or 60D or 7D paired with either a 24-70/2.8L or 70-200/2.8L IS lens

NOTE: a lens that has an opening of f/5.6 or smaller (higher f/stop number) could cause your focus lock to take longer and given the horse is moving, you may miss the shot

This is only my opinion of what I'd recommend.

Comment: You may also consider renting the equipment first before spending the money to buy it; to see if that is the equipment for you.  Considering the physical attributes of the equipment (size, weight, etc.).